# How to select the second, third, fourth.... newest folder with batch

Tags: batch-file, directory

I have written a batch which checks the newest folder for `.xml` files and copy them to another folder, after copying the files it should call an application and stop. Now I need to let the batch watch in the next folder (after completing the whole circle with the first) for any `.xml` files and do the same, and so on... With this code I can copy all the `.xml` files from the newest folder to another folder:

```
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=Y:\PriCat\Debiteuren"
SET "destindir=Y:\Pricat\Pricatombouw"
set source="Y:\Pricat\Pricatombouw"
set target="Y:\Pricat\XMLOmbouw\nieuw"
set var1=0



FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad /o-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO XCopy /y /s "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.xml" "%destindir%\" &GOTO done
:done
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove `&GOTO done` from your code. Afterwards `:done` will be useless as well so you can remove the last line, too.

Comment: @j.Cup, `GOTO done` is used to break the `FOR /f` loop upon its first iteration; due to the sort order of `dir /o`, the original code returns the most recently modified directory; so removing it lets the loop continue iterating though all folders, so this answer should be fine; if you need something different, please clarify by [editing](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/39101286/edit) your question!