# How to copy items from the second newest folder?

Tags: batch-file

I am creating a batch to copy items from the second newest folder.
This is the code to find the newest folder and copy all the `.xml` files to another location:

```dos
net use y: /delete /y
net use w: /delete /y

net use y: \\dest-fil-01\axaptaprod 
net use w: \\dest-fil-01\Access

@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=Y:\PriCat\Debiteuren"
SET "destindir=Y:\Pricat\Pricatombouw"     

FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
  'dir /b /ad /o-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
  ) DO XCopy /y /s "%sourcedir%\%%a\*.xml" "%destindir%\"
```

Do you guys know the code to find the second newest folder?

Comment: Please don't double-post! [How to select the second, third, fourth… newest folder with batch](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39101286)

Answer (score 0):

The `dir` command you use lists the folders by date so the required folder is on the 2nd line.
Let's extract it with `findstr`:

```dos
for /f "delims=: tokens=2" %%a in ('
    dir /b /ad /o-d "%sourcedir%\*" ^| findstr /n "^" ^| findstr "^2:"
') do XCopy ........
```

- `findstr /n "^"` adds numbers to all lines using `^` pattern that matches all lines
- `findstr "^2:"` gets the line that starts with `2:`, i.e. the 2nd line

Comment: Hi, thanks for anwering my question. Isn't it possible to count up? So we he have finished the firstfolder then folder + 1 or something? So i can create a good loop till it's at the fifth folder?

Comment: Yes, it's possible but only if can you define your questions properly right from the start.

Comment: so, do i need to do it right now? Of do you know what to do?

Comment: It's just basic respect for those who enjoy solving small puzzles/problems on this site. When a puzzle is solved and you tell me the goal was different it's disrespectful and really unpleasant, so... And don't tell me you didn't mean that, it won't help me regain the lost interest.

Comment: Kinda sorry for teasing you, so here's a hint: this type of processing has dozens/hundreds answers on StackOverflow and on other sites, so you can find them in a few minutes on google and so on.

Comment: Huh? How do you mean? I really liked the asnwer and it is really usefull. I then i can solve the problem now. But then i asked something different so the code gets better. Sorry if it was disrespectful, i really didn't meant that...

Comment: It's common sense. Try changing a job/task description and see how contractors will react.

Comment: Aah oke, and just further in you anwer: What do i have to type after XCopy?

Comment: Whatever was in the question.

Comment: What does this mean exactly? findstr /n "^" ^

Comment: If you don't like my description in the answer, here's a better one: It's a smiley with only one brow. A two-brow smiley would be `"^" "^"`

Comment: wait whut hahahaha